# rframe is not working in showexpl

Tags: showexpl

the option `rframe=empty` has not effect in showexpl. Here is a WME

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\begin{document}

Here is:
\begin{LTXexample}[rframe=empty]
\begin{center}
 Hello world!
\end{center}

\end{LTXexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[rframe=single]
\begin{center}
Good Bye!
\end{center}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how to delete the frame in the formatted text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty value:

```
\begin{LTXexample}[rframe=]
\begin{center}
 Hello world!
\end{center}
```